# set image resources in imageview in android

Tags: android

I am new android developer ,set image from drawable folder.

**see belove image:**

[image]

[image]

output:

[image]

[image]

when image is rectangle ,  set image view rectangle and image is square then set image view square.
how to achieve this type of functionality ?

please help me

Comment: please help to do what?

Comment: is this a question ?!!

Comment: set image in imageview .

Comment: But what is the problem definition ??

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper yes there is a question . images are square ,rectangle .and set this image to imageview. when image is rectagle ,display image rectagle in imageview.

Comment: @shree202 see above comment

Comment: why don't you get images height and width, compare them if they are equal then its square, set square image, else set rectangle image.

Comment: @Android Revolution: still not getting u? What do u mean by `image is rectagle`?

Comment: I mean are
 u getting error ?? Can u post me the work you've done. Post the java code along with your layout xml file.

Comment: `if the image is rectangle`, what do you mean by that...explain more detail

Comment: Do you mean that ImageView fit your drawable resources? Try to set scale type: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

Comment: Please clarify your problem even more, people here just have to guess the problem you might be undergoing through, if you don't give the proper definition of your problem.

Comment: @Pragnani i am editing my question .i am set image as logo in my project.

Comment: @AndroidRevolution Sorry I am still not able to understand your problem..? First of all please clearly explain your problem.. You have a ImageView and there are two images in your drawable folder. Then what do you want to achieve? When do you want to set Square and When do you want to set Rectangle? How do we know when to set

Comment: @Pragnani ,simple in drawable ,two image one square and one rectangle ,set this image in image view like my output image.

Comment: @AndroidRevolution I have understand that..but when do you want me to show rectangle Image and Square on ImageView.?

Comment: @Pragnani .Any type of image square or rectangle display in imageview as orignal.

Comment: @AndroidRevolution What is the problem  you are facing with the above it is just setting `image Resouce` to `imageview`?

Comment: @Pragnani ,yes how to set image in imageview.

Comment: @shree202 i am editing my question .try to understand my problem.please help me ....

Comment: @thank you ,it's work for me

Comment: @AndroidRevolution What is the event before setting the respective images ? Is it like, if you click on square then it should show square and if you click on Rectangle button then it should show Rectangle ?

Comment: @AndroidRevolution Ok. can you just post the code how are you checking the condition if image is rectangle or square.

Comment: @shree202 :       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            /> Drawable drawableIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.small_logo);
    imgLogo.setImageDrawable(drawableIcon);

Comment: First of all if you want to get your desired image shape then change Imageview width and height property to wrap_content instead of providing fixed 150dp.

Comment: @shree202 thank you ,but i want to fix size,because i am put image as logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered based on Comments

Try this

Place your images in `res/drawable` folder and then

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle" />      <-- your image in drawable
```